# Printing to a thermal printer with ASP.NET C# WebForms (4.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, thermal-printer

I have a requirement for a project at work to print to a thermal printer (specifically a Citizen CT-S651) that is attached to the computer via USB from ASP.NET C# Webforms. So far, I have tried a few things and did a lot of research. The main three things I have tried was using QZ Tray (formerly known as JZebra, found here https://qz.io/), however the non-free version costs too much right now, and the free version is too annoying in its popups to be of much use right now. I also tried to generate a PDF using MigraDoc (http://www.pdfsharp.net/), but when I try to print to the printer, it uses far too much paper before it even prints "Hello World" code for that shown below:

```
    private void print()
    {
        Document document = CreateDocument();
        document.UseCmykColor = true;
        const bool unicode = false;

        const PdfFontEmbedding embedding = PdfFontEmbedding.Always;

        PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(unicode, embedding);

        pdfRenderer.Document = document;

        pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();

        //pdfRenderer.Save("C:/Users/jamesl/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/TestCheckScanner/TestCheckScanner/TestDocument.pdf");


        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(stream, false);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
        Response.Flush();
        stream.Close();
        Response.End();

    }

    private Document CreateDocument()
    {
        Document document = new Document();

        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Unit width, height;

        width = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Unit.FromMillimeter(80);
        height = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Unit.FromMillimeter(50);


        Section section = document.AddSection();
        section.PageSetup.PageHeight = height;
        section.PageSetup.PageWidth = width;
        section.PageSetup.PageHeight = height;
        section.PageSetup.PageWidth = width;
        section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 0;
        section.PageSetup.RightMargin = 0;
        section.PageSetup.TopMargin = 0;


        Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();

        paragraph.Format.Font.Color = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Colors.Black; //Same as System.Drawing.Color

        paragraph.AddFormattedText("Hello, World!");

        return document;
    }
```

Since that hasn't worked very well, I have gotten it to print a little bit using PrintDocument, however, the main problems I have with this way are twofold: 1. Formatting it print a proper receipt is going to be very tedious although if it is ends up being the best way with my current constraints I am all for it. 2. This method only works if I print from Visual Studio, when I try it on the test web app I have set up on a server, I get an error of "Settings to access printer 'CITIZEN CT-S651' are not valid." Here is my code for that:

```
    private void print()
    {

        try
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "CITIZEN CT-S651";
            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            Response.End();
        }
    }

    void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Test Print", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 60, 0);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Test Again", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 60, 20);
    }
```

Any help you can give on this matter would be awesome!

Comment: Very unclear. How ASP.Net is related to printing on local printer? What kind of *single* problem you have with code shown?

Comment: I am working on an ASP.NET application, but if you say that it is unrelated then very well. 

The problem I have with the first bit of code I showed (which is one of the ways I tried to get it to work) is that it creates very long receipts (2+ feet long) for just printing "Hello World".

The other bit of code is an another, entirely separate way I tried to get it to print, but so far it has not actually worked when printing from the internet, only when testing in Visual studio.

I mentioned both of these things in my original post, but I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Just to clarify: SO can help with concrete problems, so far you have not decided what concrete problem is. You've demonstrated effort and it is good start... but not really enough for answerable SO question.

Comment: Note on "printing from the internet" - I strongly suspect that you are trying to write server side code to run on client machine... Really not going to happen.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say I don't have a concrete problem. My problem is I am not properly able to print this receipt. I am not looking for a way to fix the MigraDoc code *and* the PrintDocument code. I am not even looking for a solution for one of these. I am looking for any solution that will allow me to print a formatted receipt to a thermal printer. If that means I need to use client-side code, then very well. I simply showed this code to show what I have tried, and in the case someone had used either of these before, could tell me where I had gone wrong.

Comment: If I need to improve on my answer so that someone can answer it, I will gladly do so. I have already thought about going through it and formatting it with titles so it is a little easier to read, so if you can tell me what I need to say in order to make my question concrete, I will do it.

Comment: "Very long receipts" is a sign that you're sending the document wrong or the print driver is setup wrong.  Receipt printers use "continuous feed" paper whereas the desktop uses fixed size (e.g. A4, Letter).  Have you considered skipping the document renderer and sending raw ESC/POS bytes?